# JPA Entity Manager Merge with no changes in the object

Tags: jpa, entity

I'm trying to use Entity Manager's merge method to update an object in a database when there is no changes in the object. Say the row has the following attributes:

```
id             DECIMAL(11) NOT NULL,
name           CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
lastModified   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP
```

And say I have an object (let's call it a Person) in a database with the following attributes:

```
{id: 1, name: "example", lastModified: 2019-05-22 16:24:54.771}
```

So the lastModified attribute is something that the db updates every time there is a change on the row.

Now when I'm first fetching the object and then updating the person's name to "example" (the same value that it already has in the database), and then using using merge to update it, the lastModified attribute doesn't seem to update in the db. i.e.

```
Person person = em.find(Person.class, 1)
person.setName("example")
em.merge(person)
```

After the above actions, the lastModified is still 2019-05-22 16:24:54.771 (the same as earlier). Now if I would have changed the name i.e.

```
Person person = em.find(Person.class, 1)
person.setName("new name")
em.merge(person)
```

So now the lastModified would have updated as well.

Any help with this one? Could someone please explain me why the row doesn't update when there are no changes made to the object? :) Thanks!

Comment: when we call JPA merge(entity), If there is any changes made on entity will be persisted in to database and also vise versa. since there is no changes made on Person object (when you update same name to person object). So, it will not update the entry in to DataBase.

Comment: any how if you want to achieve , you can change lastModifiedDate like this person.setLastmodifiedDate(new Date()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `merge`, Hibernate first runs a Select statement in the tuple you're trying to merge. This select is executed to get the latest state of the tuple, to then, run the update in the database, with the data that has changed in your tuple.

As you say in your example, you haven't changed any data, as you're trying to update the name to the same as it was before, so hibernate won't run any update to the database.

You can read more about it referring to Hibernate Dirty Checking Mechanism.

If you really want to update this column even when no data's changed, you have to do it at the application layer, by setting it manually when saving the Person object:

`person.setLastModified(LocalDateTime.now())`

Comment: Thank you Marcelo for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a complement to Marcelo's answer:

You should only use `merge()` when "merging" data that is outside of the persistent context. For example, when you receive a `Person` object from a REST API not linked to the transaction scope, and you wish to connect it to the context and then persist it inside an EJB.

In your code, remove the `em.merge(person)` statement. Hibernate/JPA will detect changes when you use `set()` methods via proxy and will generate the SQL commands under the hoods.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marcelo's answer, you can force an update to the entity with a lock. Use the following:

```
em.lock(person, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
```